# WHERE clause with CASE

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I have a table that looks like this:

```
Create table testA
(
    ID int not null,
    OriginalValue int null
)

Insert into testA (ID, OriginalValue) 
values (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10), 
       (4, 10), (5, 10), (6, null), (7, null)
```

I need to show value based on

```
Declare @intExclude int = 1

Select  ID,
        OriginalValue as OriginalValue
From    testA
Where
--@intExclude = 1
Where  IsNull(OriginalValue,0) > 0 

--@intExclude = 0
where   isnull(Originalvalue,0) = 0 or IsNull(originalvalue,0) > 0
```

How do I show all value when Exclude is 0 and not o record when exclude is 1
I've tried case on where clause but with no success?

Thanks
Oded Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if that works for you ?

```
Where (@intExclude = 1
    and IsNull(OriginalValue,0) > 0 ) OR (@intExclude = 0
    and (isnull(Originalvalue,0) = 0 or IsNull(originalvalue,0) > 0 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Where (@intExclude = 1 and coalesce(OriginalValue, 0) > 0) ) or
      (@intExclude = 0 and coalesce(Originalvalue, 0) >= 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks,

It works, I also did

From   testA
Where  IsNull(OriginalValue,0) !=
             Case when @intExclude = 1
             Then (select 0)
             Else (select 1)
             End

Comment: @OdedDror . . . You actually prefer Pankaj's answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```
Declare @intExclude int = 1

Select  ID, OriginalValue
From    testA
Where (@intExclude = 1 and OriginalValue is not null)
    or (@intExclude = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks,

It works, I also did

From   testA
Where  IsNull(OriginalValue,0) !=
             Case when @intExclude = 1
             Then (select 0)
             Else (select 1)
             End

Comment: I guess the query using IsNull(OriginalValue,0) will fail if OriginalValue is zero, right?

As using IsNull converts nulls to zeros, you need to compare using "is not null"

Comment: You are correct but I my case 0 also is not considering original value.
I will add 0 into the case statement
Thanks
Oded Dror

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Where
(@intExclude = 1
and  IsNull(OriginalValue,0) > 0 ) or

(@intExclude = 0
and   isnull(Originalvalue,0) >= 0)
```